# On the eigenvalues' distribution of random unitary

Tags: probability-distributions, random-matrices, haar-measure

Fix an integer $d$, let $\mathbb{U}_d$ be the $d\times d$ unitary group.

For any $U\in \mathbb{U}_d$, define $\Omega(U)$ be the length of the smallest arc containing all the eigenvalues of $U$ on the unit circle.

Now, we are interested in the probability density function of $\Omega(U)$ as $U$ being distributed as Haar measure.

What is the probability that $\Omega(U)$ is smaller than some given constant $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 6):

This amounts to the question what is the probability distribution of the largest gap $\Delta=2\pi-\Omega$ between the eigenphases in the circular unitary ensemble. It was addressed in [Extreme gaps between eigenvalues of random matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.1294) (2010). Asymptotically for large $d$, the distribution $P(\Delta)$ is peaked around $\Delta_0=d^{-1}\sqrt{32\log d}$, with Poissonian fluctuations around this value.

Comment: Thanks! Is there explicit probability density function?

Comment: it's like all spacing distributions in random matrix theory, you only get explicit results asymptotically for large dimensionality.

Comment: Thank you! Just would like to make sure that  the " Extreme gaps" is indeed "the length of the smallest arc containing all the eigenvalues”？

Comment: "extreme gap" is "length of largest arc containing no eigenvalues", so that's the $2\pi$ minus the length of the smallest arc containing all eigenvalues, isn't it?

Comment: Very promising!

Comment: And I would like to know What is the probability that the Extreme gaps is larger than $2\pi-\epsilon$, for some small $\epsilon$?

Comment: that is just the integral of the probability distribution, which is only known asymptotically for large $d$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39290/discussion-between-gondolf-and-carlo-beenakker).